# Getting "Task is not yet complete error" when reading data using google fit android api

Tags: java, android, api, runtime-error, google-fit

I am learning Android, and my task is to retrieve steps data using Google Fit steps API. However, I keep getting "Task is not yet complete" error. I am not sure

This is my code for that part:

```
private List<Fitness> readHistoryDataFromGoogle() {
    DataReadRequest readRequest = createDataReadRequest();
    Task<DataReadResponse> response = com.google.android.gms.fitness.Fitness.getHistoryClient(this, GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this)).readData(readRequest);
    DataReadResponse responses  = response.getResult();
    List <Fitness> fitnessItems = parseFitness(responses);
    return fitnessItems;
}


private List<Fitness> parseFitness(DataReadResponse dataReadResponse) {
    List<com.example.mentalhealthapp.Fitness> fitnessItems = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Bucket bucket : dataReadResponse.getBuckets()) {
        for (DataSet set : bucket.getDataSets()) {
            for (DataPoint dataPoint : set.getDataPoints()) {
                int numSteps = dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_STEPS).asInt();
                long startDateTime = dataPoint.getStartTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                long endDateTime = dataPoint.getEndTime(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                fitnessItems.add(new com.example.mentalhealthapp.Fitness(numSteps, startDateTime, endDateTime));
            }
        }
    }
    return fitnessItems;
}
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: @a_local_nobody thank you! Initially, I tried to include onSuccessListener, but then I realised that that I can't retrieve any results since onSuccess() method by default is void. I am now considering other ways to complete this part, including RxJava. Could you please let me know how would you solve this particular task? thank you!

Comment: Yes, thank you! I have just realised my stupid mistake, I actually forgot to add a global variable and that was the reason I couldn't retrieve datapoints

Comment: considering I helped you with somthing similar, please consider upvoting my question and answer here :D https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57330766/how-to-get-data-from-any-asynchronous-operation-in-android/57330767#57330767

Comment: i'm trying to make a standard answer for these typs of questions, would appreciate your help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting this problem, because API requests (service calls) are `Asynchronous`, they don't complete and return data immediately and you can't run them line by line like other code. you have to WAIT for that response to complete before you can access the data it returns.
from the documentation it tells you it's a REST api:
[image]
[image]

**Brief look at documentation**
https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/RecordingClient suggests you should look at this for displaying data when it becomes available.